# seekbar not working in musicplayer

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface, seekbar

I am trying to create a music player app, Everything else is working fine except seekbar. I have read other similar questions on SO but its not helping at all.When song starts playing seekbar doesn't start moving. On touching the seekbar, song's total duration is displayed but not current duration or elapsed time. Also you can move song forward and backward by using seekbar but thumb position doesn't change and app stops responding. Can anyone help me with that ?

PlaylistActivity.Java

```
package com.example.dell_1.myapp3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class PlayListActivity extends Activity {

    private String[] mAudioPath;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private String[] mMusicList;
    private SeekBar songProgressBar;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    ;
    private Utilities utils;
    private TextView songCurrentDurationLabel;
    private TextView songTotalDurationLabel;
    int currentPosition = 0;

    MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriver;
    byte[] art;
    ImageView album_art;
    TextView album;
    TextView artist;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_list);
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        utils = new Utilities();

        ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        mMusicList = getAudioList();

        ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mMusicList);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                                    long arg3) {

                try {
                    playSong(mAudioPath[arg2]);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private String[] getAudioList() {
        final Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA}, null, null,
                "LOWER(" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + ") ASC");

        int count = mCursor.getCount();


        String[] songs = new String[count];
        mAudioPath = new String[count];
        int i = 0;
        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                songs[i] = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                mAudioPath[i] = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                i++;
            } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
        }

        mCursor.close();

        return songs;
    }


    private void playSong(String path) throws IllegalArgumentException,
            IllegalStateException, IOException {

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_building_music_player);
        Log.d("ringtone", "playSong :: " + path);

        mMediaPlayer.reset();
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
//mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer.start();
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                currentPosition = currentPosition + 1;
                try {
                    playSong(mAudioPath[currentPosition]);
                } catch (Exception er) {
                    er.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        acv(path);
        abc();
        cde();
        fgh();
        ijk();
        lmn();
        jjj();
    }

    public void acv(String path) {
        getInit();

        metaRetriver = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        metaRetriver.setDataSource(path);
        try {
            art = metaRetriver.getEmbeddedPicture();
            Bitmap songImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(art, 0, art.length);
            album_art.setImageBitmap(songImage);
            album.setText(metaRetriver
                    .extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM));
            artist.setText(metaRetriver
                    .extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            album_art.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            album.setText("Unknown Album");
            artist.setText("Unknown Artist");
        }

    }

    public void getInit() {
        album_art = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.coverart1);
        album = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Album);
        artist = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.artist_name);
    }


    public void abc() {
        ImageButton btnPlay1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay1);
        btnPlay1.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        btnPlay1.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                            mMediaPlayer.pause();
                        } else {
                            mMediaPlayer.start();
                        }

                    }
                });
    }


    public void cde() {
        ImageButton btnNext = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        currentPosition = currentPosition + 1;
                        try {
                            playSong(mAudioPath[currentPosition]);
                        } catch (Exception er) {
                            er.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
        );
    }

    public void fgh() {
        ImageButton btnPrevious = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
        btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        currentPosition = currentPosition - 1;
                        try {
                            playSong(mAudioPath[currentPosition]);
                        } catch (Exception er) {
                            er.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
        );
    }

    public void ijk() {
        ImageButton btnRepeat = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnRepeat);
        btnRepeat.setOnClickListener
                (new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
                    }
                });
    }

    public void lmn() {
        ImageButton btnShuffle = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnShuffle);
        btnShuffle.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        List<String> arr = Arrays.asList(mAudioPath);
                        Collections.shuffle(arr);
                        arr.toArray(mAudioPath);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    public void updateProgressBar() {
        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
    }

    /**
     * Background Runnable thread
     */
    private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            int totalDuration = mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
            long currentDuration = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

            songCurrentDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songCurrentDurationLabel);
            songTotalDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTotalDurationLabel);


            // Displaying Total Duration time
            songTotalDurationLabel.setText("" + utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
            // Displaying time completed playing
            songCurrentDurationLabel.setText("" + utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

            // Updating progress bar
            int progress = (int) (utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
            //Log.d("Progress", ""+progress);
            songProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
            songProgressBar.setMax(totalDuration);

            // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    };

            public void jjj(){
                songProgressBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.songProgressBar);

            songProgressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                    updateProgressBar();

                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
                    updateProgressBar();

                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
                    int totalDuration = mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
                    int currentPosition = utils.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(), totalDuration);

                    // forward or backward to certain seconds
                    mMediaPlayer.seekTo(currentPosition);

                    // update timer progress again
                    updateProgressBar();

                }
            });

            }
        }
```

Utilities.java

package com.example.dell_1.myapp3;

```
public class Utilities {


    public String milliSecondsToTimer(long milliseconds){
        String finalTimerString = "";
        String secondsString = "";

        int hours = (int)( milliseconds / (1000*60*60));
        int minutes = (int)(milliseconds % (1000*60*60)) / (1000*60);
        int seconds = (int) ((milliseconds % (1000*60*60)) % (1000*60) / 1000);
        if(hours > 0){
            finalTimerString = hours + ":";
        }

        if(seconds < 10){
            secondsString = "0" + seconds;
        }else{
            secondsString = "" + seconds;}

        finalTimerString = finalTimerString + minutes + ":" + secondsString;

        return finalTimerString;
    }


    public int getProgressPercentage(long currentDuration, long totalDuration){
        Double percentage = (double) 0;

        long currentSeconds = (int) (currentDuration / 1000);
        long totalSeconds = (int) (totalDuration / 1000);

        // calculating percentage
        percentage =(((double)currentSeconds)/totalSeconds)*100;

        // return percentage
        return percentage.intValue();
    }


    public int progressToTimer(int progress, int totalDuration) {
        int currentDuration = 0;
        totalDuration = (int) (totalDuration / 1000);
        currentDuration = (int) ((((double)progress) / 100) * totalDuration);

        // return current duration in milliseconds
        return currentDuration * 1000;
    }
}
```

XML File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/player_header_bg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@layout/bg_player_header"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPlaylist"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="300dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_playlist" />
    </LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/player_header_bg"
    android:paddingLeft="250dp">



    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/coverart"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:paddingLeft="250dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />


</RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/player_footer_bg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@layout/bg_player_footer"
        android:gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:weightSum="1"
           >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnPrevious"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_weight="2.40"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/btn_previous" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnPlay1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/btn_play" />


                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnNext"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/btn_next" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/songProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/player_footer_bg"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/timerDisplay"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/timerDisplay"
        android:splitTrack="false"
        android:maxHeight="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"
        android:thumb="@drawable/download8" />




    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/timerDisplay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/songProgressBar"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/songCurrentDurationLabel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#eeeeee"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/songTotalDurationLabel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#04cbde"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_above="@+id/timerDisplay"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/timerDisplay"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/timerDisplay">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/coverart1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="@drawable/download"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:paddingRight="60dp"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnRepeat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_repeat"
            android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
            android:paddingRight="6dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/coverart1"
            android:layout_alignTop = "@id/coverart1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnShuffle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_shuffle"
            android:paddingRight="6dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/coverart1"
            android:layout_alignTop = "@id/coverart1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/artist_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="330dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="null"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Album"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="380dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="null"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:gravity="center"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You only call `updateProgressBar` after a `onStopTrackingTouch` have been called

Comment: Also, you should really take the time to names thing properly. In a week, you wont remember what the method `ijk` was supposed to do and you code will slowly become unreadable even to you

Comment: Thanks , but how is calling updateProgressBar after onStopTrackingTouch wrong ?

Comment: It's not wrong, it's just that it's the only place where you call it so it will only update after that event. There is no other code to update it every n second

Comment: I see, thanks a lot

Comment: ...is the problem resolved?

Comment: no not yet :/ @JSmith I have updated the question on new problems I am facing

Comment: is your debugger working? can you set a breakpoint in your `mUpdateTimeTask` method?

Comment: seekbar is working now, thanks anyway @JSmith

Comment: ah great news :)

Comment: btw do you know how to change layout in an activity on a button click @JSmith I am using setcontentview but its not working

Comment: I do not, but this might be worth a try https://stackoverflow.com/a/17070408/1964790

Comment: I am facing issue with SeekBar can you please help me... here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54692981/android-music-seekbar-is-not-working-idle