# Change contained layouts inside a NestedScrollView dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-nestedscrollview

I am using the scrolling activity generated by Android Studio. So something like this:

[image]

It uses an `@include` tag in the XML to load the content of the activity.

I need to change the content inside this `NestedScrollView` to something else. So I have been using this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = 
(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            progressContent = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_progress, null);
            scrollView.removeView(normalContent);
            scrollView.addView(progressContent);
```

And it works, but it doesn't use the `ConstraintLayout` of the progressContent correctly, it ignored all the bias values and only keeps hard set margins and paddings.

---

In this question, people suggested to use ´setContentView` but since I only have to change the inner content, not the whole layout, it's not the right solution:
[How to set layout dynamically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070047/how-to-set-layout-dynamically-in-android)

In this one it was suggested to use `ViewStubs` instead of `@include`:
[How can I programmatically include layout in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999601/how-can-i-programmatically-include-layout-in-android)
But this only resulted in a completely broken `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and the layout parameters of the second view got discarded regardless.

---

What is the correct way of doing this?